# My App requires a model_id that is Alphanumeric 32 chars long and all I get its label are labels like "General"

Tags: model, clarifai

I have an ESP32 app that submits a picture to clarifai and get some info about it in return.

The sample App I got there is this line:

```
  // Generic model
  String model_id = "aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c";
```

Then I would like to select another model like Travel or Food for instance but my app requires the 32 chars as above and I just cannot find it for all the other models.

Assistance welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Found at:   https://www.clarifai.com/models

Answer (score 2):

One way of finding these model id's is viewing from Clarifai's portal.

Clarifai's community account is free, please signup for a community account. Upon signing into the portal at [portal.clarifai.com](https://portal.clarifai.com), follow these steps for the Travel model:

- click `my-first-application` (created by default)
- On the left panel, select Model Mode (4 little squares)
- Under 'User', select 'clarifai'
- Scroll down until you see 'travel-v1.1'
- For the visual classifier, the id is `79fbfbae4e30492b85ab2a8758273d76`, and as of today, there are 77 concepts
- If you do not provide a version ID in the API call, the default is the newest version

Model names and versions may change, so be sure to check back here if you run into issues.